# React Testing Setup with Enzyme, Mocha and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have a rails app with a react frontend which I installed using the webpacker gem. How would I set up Mocha and Enzyme to work with this?

Comment: I'd use Jest instead of Mocha, it works great, easy to setup and has so many features :)

Comment: What is the difference between Jest and Mocha? Will Jest work with air bnb's enzyme? Also do you have a link to the guide for setup?

Comment: Yes, it will work with enzyme. Jest is a test runner like Mocha, but it has more features, my favorite is the ability to run only the tests that you are working on, it automatically find out which file got updated and then it only run that suite instead of running everything again. You can also use the expect tools that comes with Jest as well as the mock API, that works really good, spying functions, etc... the Jest documentation has everything you need to get up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mocha-webpack](https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack) provides a solution for this.

TLDR:

```
yarn add mocha-webpack -D
echo "--webpack-config config/webpack/test.js" > mocha-webpack.opts
```

Then change your default `test.js` to

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const sharedConfig = require('./shared.js')
module.exports = merge(sharedConfig, {
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
})
```

Lastly, add the script to your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha-webpack test/javascript/*.spec.js"
}
```

You can require whatever you need from there in your test files like chai or enzyme.

There are also flags for stuff like `--colors` or `--recursive` that you can add to the opts file.